# How could I get the values inside the json object and the name of the object itself in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I want to get the "fruits","animals","numbers" from a JSON using c# and also I want to get the values inside the "fruits", "animals" and "numbers" I'm using the json.net but I can't be figured out how I can get the data I want.

```
{
   "fruits":[
      "apple",
      "orange",
      "grapes",
      "banana"
   ],
   "animals":[
      "cat",
      "dog",
      "lion",
      "bird",
      "horse" 
   ],
 "numbers":[
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5" 
   ]
}
```

I know I can achieve this by having this

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> fruits { get; set; }
    public List<string> animals { get; set; }
    public List<string> numbers { get; set; }
}
```

but when I add another object like colors so I need to add

```
public List<string> colors{ get; set; }
```

what I want is just simply get the object name and its values without having to define a new property.

I know this was already answered if ever please just comment some links.

Comment: `without having to create a new constructor` what do you mean by constructor?

Comment: Why not deserialise to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead?

Comment: @CodeNotFound 

I mean without creating another
 public List<string> colors{ get; set; }

Comment: @zerkms How should I do that? Thanks

Comment: @ExtendedAscii you now have got the idea - please spend some time trying solving it yourself first.

Comment: @zerkms ok , I'll try this one . I'm actually new to c#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic dictionary for your type and deserialize with the Newtonsoft JSON library. Assuming your JSON sample is in the file C:\temp\json.txt:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\json.txt");

var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);
```

then you can get your fruits or colors or whatever out of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can not make use of classes while parsing the given `JSON` because your `JSON` data is not fixed and not related to the specific items, that's why its the place where you can make use of `dynamic` object within a dictionary.
The following example demonstrates how you can make it work. I've added 2 more items i.e. cars and laptops

```
string json = "{'fruits':['apple','orange','grapes','banana']," +
                      "'animals':['cat','dog','lion','bird','horse' ]," +
                      "'cars':['bmw','mustang','suzuki']," +
                      "'laptops':['hp','acer','samsung','microsoft','mac' ]," +
                      "'numbers':['1','2','3','4','5' ]}";
        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            var objName = item.Key;
            var items = item.Value;
        }
```

Here is the execution of the above code. Hope it helps.

[image: Code Execution]